# R - Storing multiple data frames into an array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I'm new to R and was wondering if i can store multiple data frames in a vector.

Example: If i have 2 data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(CustomerId=c(1:6),Product=c(rep("Toaster",3),rep("Radio",3)))  

df2 <- data.frame(CustomerId=c(2,4,6),State=c(rep("Alabama",2),rep("Ohio",1)))
```

`df1`

```
  CustomerId Product  
1          1 Toaster  
2          2 Toaster  
3          3 Toaster  
4          4   Radio  
5          5   Radio  
6          6   Radio
```

`df2`

```
  CustomerId   State  
1          2 Alabama  
2          4 Alabama  
3          6    Ohio
```

I want store these 2 data frames in a single array df such that if I enter `>df[1]` I would get `df1` and if I enter `>df[2]` I would get `df2`.

I want to know if this is possible or even any alternate solution would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a list of data frames in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r)

Comment: I suppose you did not find the previous answer because you were looking for an array instead of a list. But if you try to store the data.frames in an array via `df <- c(df1,df2)`, you'll also create a list.

Comment: I would go with `mget(ls(pattern = "df"))` if you have many `df`s in the global envoronment

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `list`:

```
list( df1, df2 )  # -or-
list( df1=df1, df2=df2 )
```

I would be surprised if this isn't already answered somewhere on SO.